# how to access the large "Identify" digit of a Monitor Display in Windows?

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors, monitors

When setting up multiple monitors, the Windows control panel allows you to identify each monitor by drawing a large single digit over each. "1", "2", "3" etc.

Is there any way to retrieve this number programattically?

The order returned from EnumDisplayMonitors doesn't do it.
Ive also tried EnumDisplayDevices, which returns a different order.

Any clues?

Comment: The number is not exposed programmatically. The number is just something the control panel made up for its own internal purposes. There is no deep profound meaning to the number. It could've used shapes if it wanted.

Comment: I suppose so, but the problem is, people use that panel to identify a monitor, and expect the same value to correspond to entries in 3rd party software that allows for selection of a monitor.
Do you know officially that its not accessible?

Comment: It is officially not accessible.

Comment: Must ask, how do you know this?

Comment: Many others have asked the same question before, and the official answer is always the same.